# Entity Framework - Moving property from subclass to base class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to move property Tenant (of Type Tenant) from subclass to base class. I'm using TPH strategy and since I already have column `Tenant_Id` I would expect no changes in the migration.

However Entity Framework generates such a migration:

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id", "dbo.Tenants");
AddColumn("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1", c => c.Guid());
CreateIndex("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1");
AddForeignKey("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1", "dbo.Tenants", "Id");
```

How can I tell EF to utilize the same column? I don't want to have column Tenant_Id1 for obvious reasons..

Update: I was trying to do it in two steps.. First remove the property from the subclass, generate the migration and then add in the base class and generate another migrations. I was hoping that this will improve the situation - it didn't.

The problem is that the first migrations is generated empty - EF does not want to remove that field. I updated the migration to remove it, but it still stays somehow in the model. The result is that even if I add this back EF will generate it like that (still with Tenant_Id1):

```
AddColumn("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1", c => c.Guid());
CreateIndex("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1");
AddForeignKey("dbo.JobDetailsBases", "Tenant_Id1", "dbo.Tenants", "Id");
```

So now the question is: how can I alter the internal EF model to get rid of the original property which I already removed from the class?

Comment: Do you have any explicit EF mapping in your code? Like `[ForeignKey]` attributes, some mapping code in your DbContext `OnModelCreating` method, or some `EntityTypeConfiguration` class? You may have forgotten to update that info (if you are using the implicit EF conventions the entity classes are the only code you have to update, but if you are using explicit mappings you have to update them too).